# electron read remote file on boot up and share info to all component/containers

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I am new to **electron** and **react**. I want to read a remote json file on application boot up, store in a global variable and share the same information throughout the application (component / containers). Also I want to add few common methods to process the same info. How can I achieve this in electron react app?

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code.